# Query span duration in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have one gauge in my metrics, `queue_size`. I want to query, for every point in time, for how long this gauge has been nonzero.

Example data:

```
t    queue_size    desired result
0s   0             0
10s  1             0
20s  1             10
30s  2             20
40s  1             30
50s  0             0
60s  10            0
70s  5             10
80s  7             20
90s  0             0
```

The following query tells me whether `queue_size` is nonzero, but it stays constant at 1 when it is.

```
queue_size >bool 0
```

What I want instead, is for the value to increase at a rate of 1 per second, and reset as soon as `queue_size` is 0 again.

Answer (score 0):

The following is esoteric, I'd recommend finding a different way to do what you want.

Create a recording rule with:

```
size_duration = 
   (queue_size == 0)
 or 
   (size_duration + 10) * (queue_size * 0 + 1)
 or 
   queue_size * 0
```